# Water is on transparent parts of flow map three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to create a river using `three.js`, by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FT1O2G55yS8) tutorial.

Here is my displacement/height map:

[image: displacement]

And here is my flow map (transparent):

[image: flow map]

Here is the code I am using to create the river:

```js
    //Creating a texture loader
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    let s = 1;

    //DisplacementMap
    const disMap = textureLoader.load('Assets/Textures/heightmap1.jpg')
    disMap.wrapS = disMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    disMap.repeat.set(s, s);
    
    //The plane
    var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(5000, 5000);
    var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: 0x90EE90,
        displacementMap: disMap,
        displacementScale: 2
    });
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);

    scene.add(plane);

    //The flowmap and the river plane
    const flowMap = textureLoader.load('Assets/Textures/flowmap1.png')
    const river1Geo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5000, 5000)

    //The water itself
    const water = new THREE.Water(river1Geo, {
        scale: .1,
        textureWidth: 512,
        textureHeight: 512,
        flowSpeed: 0.04,
        reflectivity: 0.35,
        flowMap: flowMap,
        color: 0x87CEEB
    });
    
    //Positioning and stuff.
    water.position.z = 20;
    water.rotation.x = Math.PI*2;
    scene.add(water);
```

## My problem:

This is what I expect to see:

[image: expected]

A blue river, and nothing in the transparent areas. Instead, this is what I see:

[image: reality]

Water is flowing in one consistent direction in the transparent regions. ***Why is this? It seems to be working fine in the tutorial... is there something specific I need to do?***

## Edit:

Thanks @Mugen87!

[image: works]

Comment: Any chances to share your entire code as a live example? Or GitHub repo?

Comment: @Mugen87, of course, i will try to have that to you by the end of the day

Comment: @Mugen87, Sorry for the delay. `https://github.com/MeltdownGaming/First-Class` is the repository link. I'm using `socket.io` here to have a working chat, so If you decide to fork this you would have to run `node server.js`. This project also has a lot of other stuff besides the river for my game, but I'm using `OrbitControls` so you should be able to see what I'm talking about if you zoom out. Let me know if you need me to clean up some of the unnecessary code in order to debug the river, I'm willing to do that. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mugen87, please let me know if you have access to the github repo

Comment: Executing `node server.js` leads to the runtime error `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`. I would expect to download an npm package where I just can do `npm i && npm start`.

Comment: I've copied over the resources in `public` to a local web sever and deleted the chat logic from `index.html`. Looking at the water, it seems there is a misunderstanding how a flow map works. The flow map itself does not restrict the area where water is rendered. It seems your displacement map does not work as expected. I suggest you remove the water for now and try to get your displacement map right.

Comment: BTW: If you are using a displacement map like in your app, you should always apply a respective normal map. Otherwise the normal data do not match the displaced vertices. The normal map is usually generated together with the displacement map. It's probably best to remove the usage of a displacement map and create your terrain in Blender or a similar tool.

Comment: @Mugen87, Hmm, so it seems that the problem is with my displacement map. I tried changing the source but the only thing changing is the height of the plane, not any elevations or depressions...

Comment: @Mugen87, Do you think there's anything wrong with the way I set up the plane code? I tried commenting out the water code, but the plane isn't budging as per the displacementMap. I saw another video, `youtube.com/watch?v=2AQLMZwQpDo`, which is suggesting an `alphaMap`, but I'm not sure if that's related to this issue. How would I go about setting a `normalMap`, and what would the source be? Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: @Mugen87, going into blender now, I'm having the same problem with applying a displacement map as with `three.js`. I might just deform the plane manually in blender and then import it into three.js. I'll let you know how that goes.

Comment: That sounds like the best approach. The solution with the displacement map feels unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @Mugen87, After a lot of struggling through Blender, I finally got a plane with the appropriate depressions for the rivers. I then imported this into my code, and changed the `z` position of the water. It works perfectly now, you can see I edited my question. Thank you so much! If you want to put your comment(s) as an answer, I will gladly accept and upvote! The only thing I would say is that this seems to be slow, but I can figure that out on my own. Thanks again, you're a lifesaver!

Comment: @Mugen87 I figured out why the `displacementMap` wasn't working before in my code. I started with: `var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(5000, 5000);`, but I needed something like `var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(5000, 5000, 512, 512);`, because I needed more vertices. This method seems to work much faster than the `Blender` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't set up my plane properly. I need to change this:

```js
var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(5000, 5000);
```

to:

```js
var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(5000, 5000, 512, 512);
```

This adds more vertices for the `displacementMap` to displace.

Hope this helps anyone else stuck with the same problem~